# Removing Interdev from an IIS 5 (Windows 2000 Server) virtual directory and replacing with FTP

Tags: iis, ftp, iis-5, windows-server-2000

I've got a few sites on a `Windows 2000 box` that are still using `Interdev/HTTP` updates. I'd like to convert those to be FTP only and remove the Interdev update capability. How do I convert these with minimal disruption? I.E. How do I `remove Interdev` from these sites?

Answer (score 1):

Interdev uses FrontPage Server Extensions.  If you remove them from the virtual directory that should cut off Interdev access.

Comment: How do I remove those from a single virtual directory?